# go-json-rest: JSON payload is empty

Tags: json, rest, go

I'm trying to use [go-json-rest](https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest) to create RESTful APIs

I have this model struct:

```
type Todo struct {
    id   int
    name string
}
```

And I am trying to do a POST request to create an object of `Todo` type:

```
func CreateTodo(w rest.ResponseWriter, r *rest.Request) {

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    log.Println("body content is: ", string(body)) // here I can see {"name": "test1"}
    var todo Todo = Todo{}
    err := r.DecodeJsonPayload(&todo) // here the error shows JSON payload is empty
    defer r.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error in parsing json")
        rest.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    if todo.name == "" {
        rest.Error(w, "todo name is required", 400)
        return
    }
    lock.Lock()

    var nextId int = len(todos)
    //  todos[nextId] = todo
    todo.id = nextId // set its id
    todos = append(todos, todo)
    log.Println("num of todos: ", len(todos))
    lock.Unlock()

    w.WriteJson(&todo)
}
```

However, in the console of the POSTMAN client, the error shows:

```
{
  "Error": "JSON payload is empty"
}
```

I was wondering where might go wrong. Thanks

**Edit:**
This should not be considered a duplicate question, because I am not even trying to use the `json` package to do marshalling/unmarshalling of JSON object. Instead I am using the `rest.Request` object (built in go-json-rest) to decode the json parameters as posted from client.

After much digging and search on this problem I found this answer below resolved my issue:

> `body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)` will consume everything from the
>   request body. So after removing this line, the json parsing works!

Comment: Capitalize the struct field names `id` and `name`.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. See my edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just being silly doing `body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)` before decoding the JSON parameters without really understanding what `ioutil.ReadAll()` does to the request body.

As I quoted above in the edited post, `ioutil.ReadAll()` consumes everything in the request body, leaving nothing for the json decoder to parse. After removing the line `body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)`, the json parsing works as expected.